# How to handle HTTP response codes in Angular 5+

Tags: angular

Looking through the **Angular 5+** guidance on making HTTP requests in Services we see the basic patterns appears as follows for a service:

```
getTasks(taskId: string): Observable<ITask[]> {
  var url = this.baseServiceUrl + 'task/' + taskId;

  this.fetchedTasks = this.http.get<ITask[]>(url);

  return this.fetchedTasks;
}
```

A component may use it as follows

```
getTasks(taskId: string): void {
  this.taskService.getTasks(taskId).subscribe(tasks => this.tasks = tasks);
}
```

Using the above case, how should this be modified to allow us to handle HTTP response codes such as 400, 403, 401, 404, and 5xx.

In short, we need the caller to be aware of faulted outcomes, vs, not found, etc. so they can handle related UI concerns

Comment: Your service can use `map` and `catch`/`catchError` to return meaningful status/data back to the caller (component).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way would be to just use the error object from observable. https://xgrommx.github.io/rx-book/content/getting_started_with_rxjs/creating_and_querying_observable_sequences/error_handling.html

```
getTasks(taskId: string): void {
  this.taskService.getTasks(taskId).subscribe(data => {
        this.tasks = data;
    },
    err => {
        //handle errors here
    });
}
```

Your other options include overloading the default error handler in angular.

https://angular.io/api/core/ErrorHandler

Answer (score 3):

Your service can use `catchError` to return meaningful status/data back to the caller (component).

```
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators/catchError';
import { _throw } from 'rxjs/observable/throw';
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';


getTasks(taskId: string): Observable<ITask[]> {
  var url = this.baseServiceUrl + 'task/' + taskId;

  this.fetchedTasks = this.http.get<ITask[]>(url)
        .pipe(catchError((res: HttpErrorResponse ) => {
                if (res.status === 400) {
                    var someErrorTheCodeNeedsToReturn = something;
                    return _throw(someErrorTheCodeNeedsToReturn);
                }
                return _throw(res.status); // unknown / unexpected error, just rethrow status or do something custom
            }));
  return this.fetchedTasks;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not entirely sure with observable, though I imagine it is a similar way. I do it like this:

```
public getAllInboxMessages(): Promise<Message[]> {
    return this.http.get<Message[]>(url)
        .toPromise()
        .catch(err => this.handleError(err));
}

  public handleError(error: any): Promise<never> {
    if (error.status === 401) {
      //
    } else if (error.status === 400) {
        //
      }
        return Promise.reject(error);
  }
```